# create file in shared folder docker container

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When I try to create a file in a folder that is shared between the host and the container, I get the following error `sh: can not create *.txt: Protocol error`

I have mac os, so I use `docker-machine` in virtualbox to run container.
To summarize, I shared folder between virtualbox and host, then I shared this folder between virtualbox and container, I can see the folder contents but when I try to create a file I get an `Protocol error`

Comment: Please see if this helps - https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62490 or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197642/getting-protocol-error-when-trying-to-create-a-symlink-in-docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the shared folder in the virtualbox have the same name as the folder in the host. When I rename the shared folder in the virtualbox and I have no error, I can create file in docker container.